# Hands On Machine Learning California Housing problem

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Working through the book, and I see this bit on scikit-learn:

```
housing["income_cat"] = pd.cut(housing["median_income"], bins=[0.,1.5,3.0,4.5,6.,np.inf], labels=[1,2,3,4,5])

split =StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, randomstate=42)

for train_index, test_index in split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"])
    stat_train_set = housing.loc[train_index]
    stat_test_set = housing.loc[test_index]
```

I get that the first line is adding a column to the housing dataframe and attaching a bin 1 - 5 categorizing the income.

```
1: 0-<1.5
2: 1.5-<3.0
3: 3.0-<4.5
4: 4.5-<6
5: >6
```

I understand the second line returns a function to split.

What I don't understand is how the function knows which of the two indices is the 20%? Is the second index always the one that the function applies the test_size parameter to?

Comment: you're asking how does the function knows how to split the data into 80-20%?

Comment: No, I understand that comes from the test_size parameter in the StratifiedShuffleSplit() function. What I don’t get is how the loop knows to store the 20% sampling index in the test_index and not the train_index. Does the function always apply the test_size parameter to the second index in the loop through the .split() function?

Comment: You know the answer by urself i see ^_^
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html read here for more information

Comment: BTW dont over complicate ur head with the book a lot. when you start getting used to machine learning you will use `train_test_split` which is easier and more intuitive

Comment: So is that what it is? It always applies the test_size parameter to the second index in the loop? Or is there something in the .split() function I should be aware of?

Comment: that is it, it has the information train on the right test on the left. and btw, you can always check the length of the indexes... and even if it is 50% split for both, you can train on any split. There isnt anything special about the train or test split other than their %

Comment: Dan, you only need to know that the split method produces an iterator and this iterator yields a tuple of indices. The first element of this tuple are the train indices, the second are the test indices. There is no magic behind this.

Comment: That’s it. Thank you. That’s what I was missing. If you want credit, pop that in an answer and I’ll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to know that the split method produces an iterator and this iterator yields a tuple of indices. The first element of this tuple are the train indices, the second are the test indices. There is no magic behind this.

If you like to check the source code of the method, you can find it [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L1582). Especially look at the end of method `_iter_indices`. There you see the `yield` statement, that produces this tuple.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Btw. I love this book. It's really great and full of valuable tips and insights.